# Need assistance with CSS dropdown menus

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a CSS based dropdown and some how the dropdown stays behind the lower divs. Could anyone please check and see what am I doing wrong
Thanks in advance.

here is jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/g4CWC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the overflow property of the top panel to hidden, which hides part of the dropdown:

```
.ribbon {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try removing that line. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/yfbUC/1/

Comment: OMG.. thank you so much.. and I was trying to mess around with z-index